# Python type.function() within string format, is it possible?

Tags: python, function, types, format

Is it possible to cast a function from within a string format?

for instance:

```
print values.get('alpha').__mul__(10)
```

Prints 10. However, if you try something like:

```
values = {'alpha': 1, 'beta': 12}
print "{alpha.__mul__(10)} = 10".format(**values)
```

you get an `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__mul__(10)'`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field names in [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) are *not* Python expressions. You cannot treat them as such. They only support a limited syntax that echoes Python expressions, but are not the same thing.

Specifically, the grammar rules are:

> ```
> field_name        ::=  arg_name ("." attribute_name | "[" element_index "]")*
> arg_name          ::=  [identifier | integer]
> attribute_name    ::=  identifier
> element_index     ::=  integer | index_string
> index_string      ::=  <any source character except "]"> +
> ```

So the field name only supports attribute lookups (which are meant to be identifiers) or subscriptions.

Note that *calls* are not supported, and everything after the `.` up to the `}` is interpreted as an attribute name. Your objects do not have a `__mul__(10)` attribute; the characters `(`, `1`, `0` and `)` are seen as part of the attribute name here.

You simply cannot do what you want to do with Python and string formatting. You can support custom formats with the `object.__format__()` method, it'll be called on the object resolved. So using:

```
'{alpha:formatspec} = 10'.format(**values)
```

will result in a call to `alpha.__format__('formatspec')`; perhaps that is something you can make use of here.

Comment: I am not worried about the solution of the problem, just interested in the way string formatting works. And I think it would be powerful to have function calls from within it. Thank for your answer.